# How to add custom footer with styles in TCPDF

Tags: php, css, pdf, footer, tcpdf

I am using **TCPDF** , I am trying to add custom footer with different styles like right side `Customer Name:` color should be blue and left side `Approved By:` color should be green, and bottom of the page displaying page numbers.

I have tried this in pdf page

```
$html_content = "<table><tr><td>Customer Name:</td><td style='color:blue;'>Suneel</td><td>Approved By:</td><td style='color:green;'>Srinu</td></tr></table></hr>"    
$tcpdf->xfootertext($html_content);
```

It's Working, but it's not accept the styles

In TCPDF class

```
function Footer()
{
    $year = date('Y');
    $footertext = sprintf($this->xfootertext, $year);
    $this->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $footertext, 0, 0, false,true, "L", true);
    $this->SetY(8);
    // Set font
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0, 27, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found answer, Footer has accepted the all styles which we will parse the dynamic content with different colors.

Here is the solutions

```
$this->writeHTML($footertext, false, true, false, true);
```

Instead of

```
$this->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $footertext, 0, 0, false,true, "L", true);
```

I have changed writeHTML instead of writeHTMLCell it accept the footer colors as well.